# Positioning modal using CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am implementing the react-modal NPM library in a React Typescript project. The problem is by default the modal takes up the entire width of the screen, bar padding. I only want it a small popup in the middle of the screen but cannot seem to get it centered, as by default it seems to use absolute positioning.

Can anyone suggest how I can adapt the inline style here to have the content part appear in the middle of the overlay?

```
<ReactModal 
        isOpen={this.state.dialogOpen}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
//        portalClassName="ReactModalPortal"
//        overlayClassName="ReactModal__Overlay"
//        className="ReactModal__Content"
//        bodyOpenClassName="ReactModal__Body--open"
        shouldCloseOnEsc={true}
        shouldReturnFocusAfterClose={true}
        role="dialog"
        onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
        // tslint:disable
        parentSelector={() => document.body}
        style={{
          overlay: {
            background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)"
          },
          content: {
            width: 600,
            height:250,  
            position: "absolute",
            top: "30%",
            left: "30%",
            right: "40px",
            border: "1px solid #999",
            background: "rgba(54, 58, 67, 1)",
            overflow: "auto",
            WebkitOverflowScrolling: "touch",
            borderRadius: "6px",
            outline: "none",
            padding: "20px"          
          }
        }}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gyeLqcw8/6/ ?

Comment: Perfect, chuck it in as an answer and I'll accept, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following CSS:

```
content{
  width: "600px",
  height:"250px", 
  position: "absolute",
  z-index:"999",
  top: "30%",
  margin-left: "calc(50% - 320px)",
  border: "1px solid #999",
  background: "rgba(54, 58, 67, 1)",
  padding: "20px" 
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyeLqcw8/6)